Difference between torque about point and torque about axis
What is the difference between torque about axis and a point? Why do we calculate torque about axis sometimes and torque about point sometimes? How we can identify when to calculate torque about a point or axis in problems? Same with angular momentum

This question is similar to: Rotational dynamics about a point or an axis?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also see: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/496843/ and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/218963/


Difference between torque about point and torque about axis

One difference is the net torque about an axis produces angular acceleration about that axis. The net torque about a point produces angular acceleration about every axis (line) passing through the point except for an axis that is parallel to the direction of the net force producing the torque.

Why do we calculate torque about axis sometimes and torque about point
sometimes?

One reason for calculating the torque about an axis is if we want to know what the angular acceleration will be about that axis.
One reason for calculating the torque about a point on an object is if want to know if the object is in static equilibrium. That requires a net torque of zero about any axis through that point.

How we can identify when to calculate torque about a point or axis in
problems? Same with angular momentum

It depends on the details of the problem.
Hope this helps.
